# Selenium RC Server: Which regex options are supported for the userContentTransformation option?

Tags: regex, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using the Selenium server to run several suites of tests, and I need to modify a couple of values in each test using the userContentTransform option.

In the [Selenium server command line help](http://svn.openqa.org/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=2120/selenium-rc/website/src/main/webapp/options.html), it doesn't give any examples of the format (except a literal string replacement). It also doesn't mention which regular expression engine is running behind the scenes. Short of doing extensive research, I would like to find out what options are available to me.

Can someone provide insight into the format and options for the userContentTransform regex? (e.g. whether to provide leading and trailing slashes, whether regex flags work, and which regex features are supported.) Also, if anyone knows which engine is running behind the scenes, that would be enormously helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The `java -jar selenium-server.jar` would imply Java's regex engine, wouldn't it?

Comment: @muistooshort: Possibly, yes -- thanks. If you put that as an answer with a reference, I'll accept it. But I think it could be happening in the browser as well. So that narrows it down to two likely candidates. :)

Comment: I don't have a reference, hence the comment; I can't back it up so it isn't an answer. The option does smell like a server-side thing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Java's `java.util.regex.Pattern` syntax.  The code in question is `org.openqa.selenium.server.InjectionHelper.writeDataWithUserTransformations()`, and it uses `java.lang.String.replaceAll()` to do the job.